# in Html there's a way to make the link destination know the page which i come from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am doing a website, there are 3 starting page like "first page A" "first page B" "first page C".
each one of this page is associated to the same "final page" through a link in .

Since i want that the user is able to go back to the starting page which he come from, i add in the "Final Page" a little navbar that say (if i came from "first page A" for example):

```
<a href=""> "first page A" </a> >>> Final Page
```

so i can go back to the starting page which i come from clicking on the link.

There's a way to tell browser if i came from "first page A" write in the navbar "first page A" and if i came from the other pages write the other pages?

Thankyou so much!!

Comment: There are many ways to do this, e.g. with the `Referer` HTTP header, a query part in a URL, or cookies. So the question is really too broad. But it’s also not clear what is being asked. If you want to link to the page of the site where the user entered the site, you need do define whether you are referring to some session (and in which sense) or the first visit ever, *or* the latest visit to any of A, B, C.

Comment: it's very simple. for sake of semplicity. It's not referred to any session. It's just because i use the same page for 3 category. So when a user is in that page i just want he can go back to the category he come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use `GET` parameter to send from which page you are coming from, using parameter in your link like `finalpage.html?page=A` and get that value on your final page with `document.location.search`

here is a little function that helps you get url parameters in javascript:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}
qs = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
alert(qs.page);
```

Comment: to use get, i need to use a form with method get instead of a <a href=""> ?

Comment: no you don't. you can just use `<a href="finalpage.html?page=A">Final</a>` and get that value using above function

Comment: ok i passed the page name which i come from. 
Now i did this http://fiddle.jshell.net/rU4Tm/
but display a blank page.

Comment: check this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rU4Tm/2/ this page is your finalpage which should have the param page in url like `finalpage.html?page=A`

Comment: i have     `finalpage.html?page=A.html` in the url.

Comment: thats ok. it should work. can you alert qs.page in finalpage?

Comment: I can alert the qs.page and it's correct. It seems just getElementbyId is not working. (I put everything in a <script> in the head document)-

Comment: did you add id attribute to the <a href link that is supposed to get back to first page?

Comment: oh ok, the problem is you are running the javascript code BEFORE the link is printed out. so getElementById won't work. use body onload like i did here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KFmG8/1/

Comment: ok thank you now work! you mean because script is updated after page is generated. body onload works with every browser?

Comment: yes, script will execute once the page loads if you run it with body onload. it works with every browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript to get that info:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var prev_page = document.referrer;
</script>
```

Lets say your menu div is like below:

```
<div id="menu">
   <h2 id="menutitle">Page 1 <!--this will change dynamically now--></h2>
</menu>
```

Then use javascript to set the menu name:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var prev_page = document.referrer;
    switch(prev_page) {
        case 'http://link url here':   <!- say this page1 -->
            document.getElementById('menutitle').innerText = "Page1"


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, this is clear, so it's not safer to use method get?

Comment: You can use GET but this another option. This keeps everything in one location. And you dont have add extra elements. Both are correct and flawless solution in your case as you wont be passing important information in your get parameters...

Comment: Thank you so much for the asnwer, i will use the GET one because i think is more versatile when it come to use names with space between as link title.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var referrer = document.referrer; //stores referrer 
if( referrer && referrer != "" )
{
     //set the href to referrer
}
```